# JavaScript accessing a variable in a different file

Tags: javascript

So i am trying to access an array in index.js a different file called countries.js. However when i check the console it says that countries is not defined?

index.js

```
countries.includes('Ethiopia') ? console.log('ETHIOPIA') : countries.push('Ethiopia')
```

countries.js

```
 const countries = [
    'Albania',
    'Bolivia',
    'Canada',
    'Denmark',
    'Ethiopia',
    'Finland',
    'Germany',
    'Hungary',
    'Ireland',
    'Japan',
    'Kenya'
  ]
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="countries.js"></script>
    <script src="web_tech.js"></script>
</body>
```

All the scripts are in the index.html so im stuck as to why i cant access the variable?

Comment: The order matters; scripts are processed top to bottom. Move your index.js below countries.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the **time** you are executing code in `index.js` the `countries` variable does not exist **yet**. You need to create the variable before using:

```
<body>
    <script src="countries.js"></script>
    <!-- Now "countries" exist for index.js to use -->

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="web_tech.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is very likely a dupe, right?